# WPF change window modal state

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, window

Is it possible in WPF, to change a window from modal to non modal? That means, i open the window with `...ShowDialog();`, but later want to switch the state (like opening the window `...Show();`.

Comment: Is it a custom Window that you have written?

Comment: No, it's a simple WPF-Window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to switch the window to non-modal from the 'master' window, you could do something like this whereby Window1 becomes non-modal after 5 seconds.

The downside of this approach is that the dialog will flicker.

```
private Window1 myWindow = new Window1();

private void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Using a timer to simulate something happening 5 seconds later that would cause dialog state to change
    DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
    // The following line will block until you switch the dialog from modal to non-modal
    myWindow.ShowDialog();            
}

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as DispatcherTimer).Stop();
    myWindow.Hide();
    myWindow.Show();
}
```

If you want to want to switch the window to non-modal from the window itself, then a call to Hide() followed by Show() will accomplish the same thing (again with flicker)

```
private void SwitchToModelessButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    this.Show();
}
```

It is worth noting that the 'master' windows call to ShowDialog() will return when you make this switch.

Comment: No, the customer requests a Button in the modal window, switching the state. But `this.Hide()` and than `this.Show()` should also work, i try this.

Comment: Ah, that's why I asked if it was a custom Window.

Comment: Ok, in my simple demo, this works: `private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TestWindow w = new TestWindow();
            w.ShowDialog();
        }`. Is there another solution, without hide and show?

Comment: Edited the answer to include hiding from the dialog window code. I don't know of any other ways without hiding the window first, but I'm happy to be proved wrong if someone comes up with an alternative. This should at least achieve what you need.